# Exact search is not working properly

Tags: discussion, bug, search

I want to find posts that contain `\tikz{` but using `"\tikz{"` does not help. Is this a bug? How can I do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Searching for symbols isn't fully supported (just like regular search engines have problems with that). What you *can* do, since `\tikz{` is usually used inside code blocks, is to search for [`code:"\tikz{"`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=code%3A%22%5Ctikz%7B%22) which does seem to produce the correct results; [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65268/moving-tiles-of-the-pattern-in-tikz/65270#65270) is the top hit right now.

[image]